# If a questions prefers answer from one school of Fiqh should answers from other schools be deleted by moderators?

Tags: discussion, moderators

This meta question is not limited to this question but as example in [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2699/does-the-three-times-count-still-apply-if-we-use-detergent/2721#comment9931_2721) the the answer from Jafari Fiqh is deleted by a moderator. this question can be the question of Muslims from different schools and having an answer from other schools can be useful for followers of other schools.

Also the question is not asking clearly for answer only from a specific school.

Even if question is asked for a specific school, the answers from other schools can be useful.

Also The Jafari Fiqh answer is valid for a Hanafi Muslim because:

> there have been numerous fatwas regarding the acceptance of Jaʿfarī
>   fiqh as an acceptable Muslim madhhab by Sunni religious bodies. These
>   include the Amman Message and a fatwa by Al-Azhar

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ja%27fari_jurisprudence

when Islamic scholars allow using Jafari Fiqh for Hanafi Muslims,  Jafari Fiqh answer is on topic also. unless we want to disagree scholars.

Also this site is claimed to be a Multi view site. other Muslims maybe have similar question and while a question does not explicitly limit the answer to a specific school other answers can be useful for other users.

Also please note explicitly asking for answer from a specific school is different of preferred school. only if explicit should be deleted and not if preferred.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, they should be deleted.** Questions that ask specifically for one view (be it Hanafi, Sunni, Shi'a, etc.) should be *answered based on that view.* Other views don't matter to the questioner; they're just noise. At best, they are just clutter; at worst, they may get upvotes, and future readers will have to dig through the answers to find the actual answer to their question.

goldPseudo's actions and his answers above are correctly inline with the SE model. You can see what he linked for more details.

---

The question explicitly asked for the Hanafi view:

> I know (In Hanafi school of law or Madhab) ...

The Hanafi madhab is a sunni Islam madhab, so posting a Jafari/shi'a view goes against what the questioner asked.

Even more interesting, you raise this complaint after you yourself edited the question to include:

> Hanafi school view is preferred but view of other schools is welcomed.

So you interpreted the question your own way, edited it to fit your interpretation, and then answered it. The question asked very explicitly for the Hanafi madhab view, so we deleted your answer.

Comment: he does not say that he wants answers only from hanafi mazhab, only says sources of his knowledge. and take in account that the answers maybe useful for other readers of this site, if not for who asked.

Answer (score 1):

From [the FAQ](https://islam.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion): (emphasis mine)

> Do expect to see answers from multiple points of view, ***unless a certain point of view is specifically requested in the question***.

Also from the FAQ:

> Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed.

So, in short, yes.  If a question is explicitly asked in regards to a particular school of thought, then answers from differing schools of thought should be removed.  Ideally this would be done by the community at large via delete votes, but we still lack enough active power users to do so reliably; as such the job currently falls on the moderators to keep things clean.

Cluttering the site with posts that *do not even answer the question asked* flies directly in the face of the Stack Exchange philosophy: Building a library of **high-quality questions and answers**.

See also the Stack Exchange guide on [how to make your answer great](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer).

Comment: the hanafi Muslims are allowed to follow Jafari school also. so this jafari is valid for hanafi school. also the question does not request a specific school answer. it says in hanafi I know... instead of deleting answer it is better to edit question to include all schools but with preferred school to keep site a real multi view and no need for similar question for every school. one question with answer from schools is better to 5 similar question with requesting specific school.

Comment: @ahmadi If you want to propose a "multi-sect answers should be allowed on all questions" policy, you are free to do so; that however is an entirely different discussion.  As per the title, this thread is about moderator actions inre enforcement and interpretation of community and site policy, which is what i answered.

Comment: OK. but I do not think that question explicitly asked in regards to a particular school of thought. prefer is different of  "explicitly asking a particular school". when a school prefered other schools can be included in answers. also when Jafari Fiqh is accepted bu Hanafi Muslims scholars the matter changes.

Answer (score -1):

- If the question *explicitly* (with no room for interpretation) says "I want answers from X sect/school", then answers that don't follow should be deleted.
- If there is room for interpretation, like Ahamadi's view that Jaffari fiqh is fine for a Hanafi, then the OP should be asked *first*. If OP gives their consent, then answer away. If they don't give consent (or do not respond), then answers that don't follow should be deleted.

Comment: I think that question did not explicitly said "I want answers from X sect/school". please note a QA is not only for who asks question. others are using this site also. and a answer from other school can be useful for other users eve if not usable for asker. I think you are making this site very tough and strict and undecorated. this is a barrier for growth of this site. also this is a wiki site and I edited the question like many of my questions are edited. now what is problem? it should be deleted now. may Allah forgive and guide me and you.